# Aurelia html attribute binding

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I would like to bind html attribute "required".
I have my template and model. I do pass a lot of info like label value `label.bind="fieldLabel"` but I would like also pass if element is required or not. Simple `required="true/false"` or `required="required/not-required"` does not work.
Digging threw web I found some statement that it is not possible, and to do it in Aurelia I need to use pure js `.setAttribute()`. Is it true? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
I had small differences.
Now:
element should have `required="isRequired"`, it should be declared in ts file as boolean, and use looks like `is-requider.bind="true/false"`
thats it folks